# How to return the middle character of a string in python?

Tags: python, string

*Full problem:*

> Write a function named mid that takes a string as its parameter. Your function should extract and return the middle letter. If there is no middle letter, your function should return the empty string. For example, `mid("abc")` should return "b" and `mid("aaaa")` should return "".

*Question:*

How come at the very end `print(x)` and everything works as expected, but `return x` breaks the program with the following:

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
import math
def mid(string):
    enum = list(enumerate(string))
    lastnum = enum[-1][0] + 1
    if lastnum % 2 == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        middle = math.floor(len(enum)/2)
        x = enum[middle][1]
        print(x)
        return x

mid("asaba")
```

Comment: While your code can be improved, for me, your code works fine for the "asaba" case - I don't see why you would get IndexError for "asaba" input.  As stated in the question linked by baduker, your code you have issues with the empty string.  If you can use a debugger, it can be helpful to step through your code to see what the variables are at each point.  Also, the stack trace of the exception will tell you what line the exception happened on, which can give a useful clue as to which index operation is the problem.
Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! This community is very helpful and Im pleasantly surprised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails on edge cases, specifically when given the empty string, but I found during my tests that it works for strings like `"asaba"`, `"aaaa"`, and `"abc"` but throws the error when given `""`. The reason for this is because `lastnum = enum[-1][0] + 1` will give an index that does not exist for the empty string. The way to fix this would be to add a condition at the beginning of your function that checks if it's an empty string, so like this:

```
if len(string) == 0:
    return ""
```

Comment: This ended up being the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how I would approach it:

```
def mid(string):
    if len(string) % 2 == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        offset = int(len(string) / 2)
        return string[offset: offset + 1]

mid("abc")
mid("asaba")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math 

def mid(string_1):
    string_2 = ''
    if len(string_1) %2 == 0:
        return string_2
    else:
        string_2 = string_1[math.floor(len(string_1)/2)]
        return string_2

print(mid("abc"))
```

I've done the function in this way and it works fine, the logic is the following:

If the length of the string is even return an empty string ""

If the length of the string is odd then returns the middle character, this is done by finding the index in the middle:

```
string_2 = string_1[math.floor(len(string_1)/2)]
```